# Same id for every object created by react-from

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to make a working *react redux* form. Although I have a problem. Every element which I add using my form has **same Id**.

It might be because of the fact that I put the `id` as `defaultValue`:

```
id: uuidv4()
```

But I can't figure it out where should I exactly put this line, so on every submit my newly created element would have new changed `id`.

Whole code of `TodoForm`:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodos } from "../redux/reducer";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    todos: state,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addTodo: (obj) => dispatch(addTodos(obj)),
});

const TodoForm = (props) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            id: uuidv4(),
            name: "",
            date: "",
            done: false,
        },
    });

    console.log(props);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(props.addTodo)}>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                name="name"
                {...register("name", { required: true })}
            />
            <input
                type="date"
                placeholder="Date"
                name="date"
                {...register("date", { required: true })}
            />

            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoForm);
```

Comment: Looking at the docs for the npm package, import like so: `import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';` and then inside of your `TodoForm` function, create a new variable like so: `var uniqueId = uuid();` and then inside of your `<input` tag, specify `<input id={uniqueId}`. Doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4

Comment: this does not change anything, still all the element are created with same id

Comment: Yes, you need to create a different variable for each input using the `uuid()` function (or alternatively, do: `<input id={uuid()}` ) and remove the `id: uuidv4(),` from the `defaultValues` array.

Comment: in which input should i pass this id={uuid()}

Comment: As you want unique id's for both inputs, add it to both of them, this would create a unique ID for both the inputs.

Comment: it doesnt work ;p

Comment: I'm setting up my environment now so I can give it a go myself, will update once done

Comment: Generally please note that Redux-Form is deprecated by the authors for multiple years by now and you are writing a very outdated style of Redux here. If you are just learning this, you are probably following a very outdated resource. I'd recommend going with the official Redux tutorial (https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) and managing forms with another library (not Redux).

Comment: @phry well, i already noticed that they are people using reduxjs/toolkit. Is this the proper path i should take?

Comment: The official Redux tutorial I linked above teaches exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from our conversation in the comments, I have made this very simplistic version of the form you are creating:

```
function TodoForm()
{
  var nameId = uuid();
  var dateId = uuid();
    
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        id={nameId}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="name"
      />
      <input
        id={dateId}
        type="date"
        placeholder="Date"
        name="date"
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Which when I look at the Developer Console, results in the following:

[image: Screenshot of Dev Console]

As you can see, the resulting ID for each input is unique as you require, again, just make sure you remove the following: `id: uuidv4(),` from the `defaultValues` array.